# PHP header authentication with Password only

Tags: php, authentication, passwords, prompt

I've found following code

```
<?php
$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] = 'Me';

if (empty($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'])) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo 'Text to send if user hits Cancel button';
    exit;
} else {
    echo "<p>Hello {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}.</p>";
    echo "<p>You entered {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']} as your password.</p>";
}
?>
```

according to the above code, it prompts a username and password empty fields. I'm trying to find a way to force a username to always show up, but keeping password for the user to type it.
So is there a way to always lock the username ? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP Basic Authentication is specified in [RFC 2617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617). I did not found anything about a *default user name* there. That's why I would say it is impossible to set this by the server. But some browsers may cache the user name and password if you have once logged in.

Answer (score 0):

This will never happen because HTTP is a stateless protocol by definition.

You can, however, include the credentials within the request URI:

```
https://username:password@www.example.com/path
```